# Wrong number or types of arguments in call to stored procedure in Oracle using Spring Data Jpa

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to call a stored procedure block in Oracle using spring data jpa and getting the mentioned error.
Following are the snippets

dao

```
    @Transactional
    @Procedure(name="createUser")
    void createUser(@Param("corpID")String corpID,@Param("password")String password);
```

Stored procedure as defined in Oracle database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE createUser
(corpId IN VARCHAR2, passwd IN VARCHAR2) IS
    -- [declaration_section]\
    DDL_STMT VARCHAR2(400);
BEGIN    
    -- executable_section
    DDL_STMT:= 'CREATE USER  "'|| corpId || '" IDENTIFIED BY "' || passwd || '" DEFAULT TABLESPACE RDSADMIN TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP PROFILE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DDL STATEMENT EXECUTED:'||DDL_STMT);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DDL_STMT;
END;
```

Complete Error Trace

```
Hibernate: {call createUser(?,?)}
2020-01-08 08:29:43.628 TRACE 18101 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [corpID] as [VARCHAR] - [KKOHLI1]
2020-01-08 08:29:43.629 TRACE 18101 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [password] as [VARCHAR] - [U3XRtw8Vy9D&]
2020-01-08 08:29:44.163  WARN 18101 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
2020-01-08 08:29:44.164 ERROR 18101 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATEUSER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

2020-01-08 08:29:44.466 ERROR 18101 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [createUser]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATEUSER'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:249) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:82) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:924) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1318) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3752) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4242) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:18.3.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:631) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:614) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:314) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.createUser(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.intuit.HeimdallService.createUser(HeimdallService.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.intuit.HeimdallService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$587648c7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.intuit.HeimdallService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d57f276.createUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.intuit.HeimdallController.createUser(HeimdallController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Comment: What happens when yoh call the proc directly from plsql developer or sqlplus? Remove double quotes from ddl_stmt string and try to execute.

Comment: exec createUser('kkohli','Qwerty123!'); call is going through fine. The reason why I added the double quotes was because for password the query doesn't work if it is not enclosed in double quotes so I reckoned having both username and password in double quotes

Comment: can you please try with `@Param("passwd")String password` instead of `@Param("password")String password`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if i remember correctly i believe the parameter name in the `@Param` annotation needs to match the parameter name in the stored procedure.

So try changing it to "corpId" and "passwd":

```
void createUser(@Param("corpId")String corpID,@Param("passwd")String password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this answer as it helped me a lot!
I also, after adjusting the parameters name with @Param (), I had to adjust the procedure name by adding the name of the oracle package where it is contained.
Example:

```
@Repository
public interface MaintenanceRepository extends JpaRepository<MaintenanceView, Long> {
    
    @Transactional
    @Procedure(procedureName = "PKG_MAINTENANCE.UPDATE_INTEGRATION")
    void updateMaintenanceStatus(@Param("in_maintenace_id") String 
     maintenanceHistoryId, 
    @Param("in_integration_date") String integrationDate , @Param("in_integration_id") 
    String maintenanceIntegrationId);
}
```